# Given a monotonic increasing function, prove inequalities related to it's integral and summations

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-sum

> Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a monotonic increasing function such that $f(0)=0, f(1)=1.$
>
> $(a)$ Prove for all $n$:
>   $$\int_0^1f(x)dx \leq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^nf(\frac{j}{n}) \leq \int_0^1f(x)dx +\frac{1}{n}$$
>
> $(b)$ Prove for all $n$:
>   $$\int_0^1f(x)dx \leq \frac{2}{n^2}\sum_{j=1}^njf(\frac{j^2}{n^2})$$

My try:

$(a)$ Let us set a partition $\Pi_n$ of the interval $[0,1]$ of $n$ intervals of the same length and pick the end points of each interval as $t_n.$

We get the Riemann sum of $f(x),$ which is integrable, so when $n \rightarrow \infty, \lambda(\Pi_n)\rightarrow 0,$ and we get:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{1}{n}f(\frac{j}{n})=\lim_{n\to \infty}S(f,\Pi_n,t_n)= \int_0^1f(x)dx $$

I can see that for $j=n$, we get $\frac{1}{n}f(1)=\frac{1}{n}$. Can I take it out of the summation (obviously won't affect the integral) and then because of the monotonicity we get right inequality ?

As for the left inequality, I belive we should use that $f(0)=0$, but can't really see how.

$(b)$ I think, in the same way as in $(a)$, we can get the Riemann sum of $2xf(x^2)$, but can't really get further.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: (b) is easy and you got the clue. Just notice that $\int_0^1 2tf(t^2)dt = \int_0^1 f(x)dx$ and that $2tf(t)$ is also an increasing function so that $\int_0^1 2tf(t^2)dt\le \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{2j}{n^2} f(\frac{j^2}{n^2})$

Comment: @SiddharthJoshi How do you get the second inequality? From $(a)?$

Comment: Take $g(t)=2tf(t^2)$. Then $\int_0^1 2rf(r^2) dr = \int_0^1 g(t) dt \le \frac1n \sum_{j=1}^n g(\frac j n)$ which you can prove for all positive-valued increasing functions (inequality (a)), and $\sum_{j=1}^n g(\frac j n) = \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{2j}n f(\frac{j^2}{n^2})$ |- substitute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

For (a) use

$$\frac{1}{n} f\left(\frac{j-1}{n} \right) \leqslant \int_{(j-1)/n}^{j/n}f(x) \, dx \leqslant \frac{1}{n} f\left(\frac{j}{n} \right)$$

and sum from $j=1$ to $n$, yielding

$$\frac{f(0)}{n} +  \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n f\left(\frac{j}{n} \right) - \frac{f(1)}{n} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n f\left(\frac{j-1}{n} \right) \leqslant \int_{0}^{1}f(x) \, dx \leqslant \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^nf\left(\frac{j}{n} \right),$$

and, since $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$,

$$\tag{*}\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n f\left(\frac{j}{n} \right) - \frac{1}{n} \leqslant \int_{0}^{1}f(x) \, dx \leqslant \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^nf\left(\frac{j}{n} \right).$$

For (b)

$$\int_{(j-1)^2/n^2}^{j^2/n^2}f(x) \, dx \leqslant \frac{(2j-1)}{n^2} f\left(\frac{j^2}{n^2} \right)$$

Comment: Could you please explain why the sum of the middle term ends up in the required sum?

Comment: Now rearrange (*) to put the sum in the middle of a chain of inequalities.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification. How could I come up with the first chain of inequalities, what's the intuition?

Comment: The function is increasing so if $(j-1)/n \leqslant x \leqslant j/n$ we have $f((j-1)/n) \leqslant f(x) \leqslant f(j/n)$.  Integration over $[(j-1)/n , j/n]$preserves the order and for example $\int_{(j-1)/n}^{j/n} f(j/n) \, dx = f(j/n)[ j/n - (j-1)/n] = f(j/n)/n$.  The point is this does not require taking limits of Riemann sums.